# Splitting autogenerated C# file

Tags: c#, auto-generate

I have a huge autogenerated C# file. It contains many enums and many classes.
The file is so big that it regularly blocks Visual Studio when it updates intellisense.

I would like to chop the file to smaller segments. For example just separating the enums and classes would already be nice.

Is there an easy way to do that?

EDIT: The file was generated from 4 XSD schemas (importing one another) using XSD.exe. It was generated only once. The schemas do not change. Generating code from the schemas one by one would be OK, if I could convince XSD.exe to ignore the imported types from the generation process.

Comment: How is the file generated?

Comment: You should really look into the code generation algorithm to see if you can make some modifications there to seperate each class into a seperate file. If it's a T4 template it can't be that difficult.

Comment: What triggers it to update intelligence (it sounds like you've only generated this file once, then it hasn't changed)? Would putting it in a seperate project help?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), ie a class defined in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, usually 99.9% of auto-generated code is best left untouched and these days can be extended using partial classes or sub classing.  It would all depend on if you ever intend to run the process that produced the auto-generated code.  But generally editing auto-generated code is usually a no-no and consequently one of the biggest consequences of code auto-generation.

Answer (score 0):

[Partial classes feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) is there to address this. But since you haven't provided how or which tool generated the code, can't predict what would happen in Updating the code. If the code generation is in your control, you could update it to generate the files with Partial classes in the first place so that updates are easily managed.

Otherwise it's better not doing this separation if these code generated frequently.